# Classification of $3$-dimensional Manifolds using Euler-Characteristic?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, manifolds

For some research project, I am in the situation where I have different simplicial complexes in three dimensions. From some given complex, one can easily read of the Euler charactersitc
$$\chi=V-E+F-T$$
where $V$ is the number of vertices, $E$ is the number of edges, $F$ is the number of faces (triangles) and $T$ is the number of $3$-simplices (tetrahedra). Now to my question: Is there a classification theorem for $3$-dimensional manifolds using the Euler-characterstic such that I can tell which topology such complexes describe? Some easy cases are clear: $\chi=1$ corresponds to a ball (since contractible) and $\chi=0$  to a solid torus, since $\chi(Solid\,Torus)=\chi(Disk\times S^{1})=\chi(Disk)\cdot\chi(S^{1})=1\cdot 0=0$.

More precisely, is there any classification theorem similar to the $2$-dimensional case, where (compact, oriented) surfaces are classified in terms of there genera?

Comment: A topological classification of 3-manifolds is possible, but *much* more complicated than the 2-dimensional case (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-manifold#Invariants_describing_3-manifolds) for some examples). The Euler characteristic is not sufficient; for instance, there are many other $3$-manifolds with $\chi=0$.

Comment: Okay, thank you ver much. But the Euler characteristic is still a topological invariant in higher dimensions right? However, in $d>2$ dimensions it can happen that several non-homeomorphic manifolds have the same Euler characteristic and hence it cannot be used for classification. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In fact, no homotopy invariants will suffice for a classification, since there are [lens spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space) which are homotopy equivalent but not homeomorphic.

Comment: IIRC, the Euler characteristic of every closed (compact, boundaryless) $3$-manifold is zero....