# Triangulations of $3$-dimensional Manifold: Which Topology?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, 3d, simplicial-complex, triangulation

When I have some (abstract) $3$-dimensional simplicial complex, is it possible to "read of" which topology it describes. A little bit more precisely: Suppose I have a simplicial compelx and that I know that it really describes a (compact, oriented) manifold (and not a pseudo-manifold) possibly with boundary. Is it then possible to tell to which $3$-dimensional manifold the corresponding geometric realization is homeomorphic to, or in other words, which topology describes?

For $2$-dimensional complexes this is quite simple, because I can always read off the Euler characteristic $\chi=V-E+T$ and since compact orientable surfaces are classified by their genera we are done. However, as I have learnt from a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232782/classification-of-3-dimensional-manifolds-using-euler-characteristic), $3$-dimensional (compact, oriented) manifolds are not classified by their genera. In particular, one can show that every closed odd-dimensional manifold has Euler characteristic zero. In the case of manifolds with boundary, this can also be understood as a special case of the statement that every compact and orientable $3$-manifold with boundary has half the Euler characteristic of its boundary.

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to asking the question "Is there some combinatorial invariant of a compact oriented 3-manifold that I can compute and then compare to a complete list of compact oriented 3-manifolds to know which one I've got?" As far as I know, there is no complete list of compact oriented 3-manifolds. You're scratching the surface of some pretty deep maths (Geometrization, Poincaré conjecture). Some types of 3-manifolds are classified by fundamental group (e.g. hyperbolic manifolds), but it's not easy to tell definitively whether a manifold is hyperbolic or not.

Comment: I think the short answer to your question is 'No'. The long answer is, "Theoretically, maybe. Go ahead and come up with a classification and a recognition algorithm, and you'll probably get a Fields medal".

Comment: Okay thank you very much! Very interesting, but a little bit unfortunate for my purposes. :'-).

Comment: In sufficiently high dimensions (4 and higher, if I remember correctly) then it is a theorem that there is *no* algorithm that can determine whether two triangulations give homeomorphic manifolds.